# How to implement C++ style Union in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

Is there a way to implement C++ style Union in C#? I will also need to serialize this "Union" to disk.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? There might be other language features you could use instead

Comment: Which ones?
Thx EitanB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simluate it with the `StructLayoutAttribute` and `FieldOffsetAttribute`:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct ExampleStruct
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int a;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int b;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int c;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int d;
}
```

C# doesn't have direct support for them.. but this gets you closer. See this MSDN example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acxa5b99(v=vs.80).aspx.

As for how you'll go serializing it.. haven't tried it myself (haven't had the need to..).

Comment: Thank you very much, however I am trying to do something a more more complex in terms of the variables:

I want to store in a file data that can be of diffrenet structure types:

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct ABC{
[FieldOffset(0)]
public Class1 class1;

[FieldOffset(0)]
public Class2 class2;

[FieldOffset(0)]
public Class3 class3;
}

but this method is good for simple types where you can calculate the amount of memory each variable will occupy :(

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to implement a C-style union in C# but you can implement something that has Union semantics.

The question you really have to ask yourself at this point is: **What exactly is the reason you need a C-style union in the first place?** And the answer to that question will probably lead you to your next question..

The C-style unions solved a problem that made sense in the context of C where the memory used to be rather sparse and the type-system not very strict, as is the case with .NET

In C# you could use a struct and attributes to get union semantics but you should really consider carefully the underlying problem you are trying to solve!

Comment: I want to store in a file data that can be of diffrenet structure types:
struct ABC{
[FieldOffset(0)]
public Class1 class1;
public Class2 class2;
public Class3 class3;
}

but to have the class1, class

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ipv4
{

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct IPv4Address
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public uint Address;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public byte b3;
        [FieldOffset(1)]
        public byte b2;
        [FieldOffset(2)]
        public byte b1;
        [FieldOffset(3)]
        public byte b0;
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPv4Address myAddress;

            // Assign localhost to the IPv4 address
            myAddress.Address = 0; // Avoid CS0170: Unassigned Field error
            myAddress.b0 = 127;
            myAddress.b1 = 0;
            myAddress.b2 = 0;
            myAddress.b3 = 1;

            Console.WriteLine("The address in hexadecimal: {0:x}",myAddress.Address);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you know what a C++ union is and you know C#, there is really not much to explain about this code.

Comment: @willsimmons as the question was asked, the OP needs the explanations, at least on C#, I guess

Answer (score 1):

`dynamic` can be considered somewhat close to union as variable of such type can hold anything.

```
dynamic a = 3;
a = "test";
```